# Accessing beans in View Class

Tags: sugarcrm

Hi I'm still very new to SugarCRM and trying to get my head round sugars MVC.

I'm making a module which doesn't have its own SugarBean instead it needs to interact with the Contacts Beans and Quotes Bean.

My example code is below.

My Question is how can i get access to the $contact_bean and $quote_bean from the controller.php in the view.searchengineer.php file so i can call information from them after the records have been loaded.

controller.php

```
Class PCP_TasksController extends SugarController
{
    function action_search_engineers()
    {
       // Get Contacts ID
       $contact_id = $_GET['Contact_id'];
       //Load Contacts Bean and pull Record
       $contact_bean = New Contact();
       $contact_bean->retrieve($contact_id );

       //Get Quote ID
       $quote_id = $_GET['Quote_id'];
       //Load Quotes Module and pull record
       $quote_bean = New AOS_Quotes();
       $quote_bean->retrieve($quote_id );


       $this->view = 'SearchEngineer';
    }

}
```

views/view.searchengineer.php

```
class PCP_tasksViewSearchengineer extends SugarView
{

   function display() { 

       Echo "The Contact Name is ";

       Echo "The Quote Ref is ";
   }

}
```

Comment: Do i need to use $this->view_object_map array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put that same code directly in the view instead.

Comment: I thought the point of MVC is to split the general logic away from the view logic.

Comment: Agreed but how the MVC model is implemented is out of your control here. In this case, you can have it working simply by moving it over or you can try to jam it in to get it to work in the controller while probably introducing even more possible failure points. The less you have to customize the better when it comes to SugarCRM.